# Java was started but returned exit code=1?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-luna

I recently updated java and came across this error... I've changed my eclipse.ini file to the

```
-vm 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
```

Yet it still doesn't work... here is the whole ini file

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-XX:-UseCompressedOops
-vm 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Any solutions? I don't know what to do

Comment: Try to minimize max heap space...

Comment: how exactly would i do that? Sorry I'm a c++ beginner have only been coding for a few weeks

Comment: if you have already installed jdk 1.7 then try to change `-Xms40m
-Xmx512m` to `-Xms40m -Xmx128m`in your `eclipse.ini` file.

Comment: I had similar problems a while back. It turned out my Java installation was knackered. Can you run java -version from the command prompt? If not try uninstalling and reinstalling Java. The latest JDK is 8u40.

Comment: @Goose I got this "Error occured during intialization of VM java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/object

Comment: I would uninstall Java, reboot, download latest from web (JDK) and reinstall.

Comment: @Goose should I also reinstall eclipse?

Comment: If the JDK reinstall doesn't solve it there no harm trying.

Comment: @Goose Thank you so much... it was the JDK... it was corrupted or something? A fresh installation fixed it. Much love to you and thank you for taking the time to answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the JAVA_HOME variable and path was set properly.
I added the below, which resolved this issue.

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\javaw.exe
```

Make sure, that the -vm option occurs before the -vmargs command.

Answer (score 1):

The error message points to a problem with your java Version. Do you have a JDK installed?

Try adding:

```
-vm 
c:/wherever/java/jdk1.8.0_40/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll
```

to your eclipse.ini file, pointing to the JDK you want to use, and check that the required Java Verision is at least as new as your JDK. This is the path for a Windows system.

Comment: These are the versions I currently have:  http://gyazo.com/d7be3ace9460d4fe8d2e2a3425110deb

Comment: @lovestogame227 As per your JDK version, I updated the solution. Check it

Comment: I did that and end up with this: http://gyazo.com/63a81c01f677a3384469896a0d918ae4 however I end up now with A java runtime environment (JRE) or JDK must be available in order to run eclipse

Comment: '-vm' and the path must **always** be on separate lines in the eclipse.ini

Answer (score 1):

Discovered the issue thanks to @Goose.

My JDK version was somehow not working? A fresh installation of Java and JDK seemed to resolve the issue as well as the rerouting of the ini file to:

-vm 
c:/wherever/java/jdk1.8.0_40/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll

Comment: A re-install of the JDK is all that was needed to resolve my (same) issue. No need to hard link any jdk in the ini file, in fact I would recommend against the -vm option as it will cause problems on your next JVM/JDK update (if you're like me, you'll forgot you added that line).

Answer (score 0):

i have removed the same path which is displaying in error message from system environmental variables [ In "Path" Variable]